# I just upgraded to PHP5 - Everything is deprecated, Apache is blank

Tags: php, nginx, apache2, deprecated, php-5.5

I have no idea of what version of PHP I was using before, but I'm guessing it was an older version because it was working just fine before I switched from Nginx to Apache. I think I was using an older version of PHP on Nginx. Anyhow this is an example of code that is said to be deprecated. I am now on PHP 5.5.9.

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("database", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select name from table where name='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['name'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

All of my pages use PHP code similar to this so I'm just going to post one of them. This is my error log.

```
[Mon Jan 12 03:03:40.456254 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2415:tid 3074542208] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 12 03:03:40.456344 2015] [core:notice] [pid 2415:tid 3074542208] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jan 12 03:04:42.038619 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2415:tid 3074542208] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jan 12 03:04:43.100702 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3617] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 12 03:04:43.100786 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3617] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jan 12 03:04:44.344041 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3617] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jan 12 03:04:45.489917 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3708] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 12 03:04:45.489959 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3708] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jan 12 03:06:19.837552 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3708] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jan 12 03:06:20.873964 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3925] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 12 03:06:20.874005 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3925] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jan 12 03:07:37.795009 2015] [:error] [pid 3932] [client 108.162.238.215:57356] script '/var/www/html/info.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jan 12 03:09:01.713565 2015] [:error] [pid 3928] [client 108.162.238.215:28781] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 4
[Mon Jan 12 03:09:06.002298 2015] [:error] [pid 3928] [client 108.162.238.215:28781] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 4
[Mon Jan 12 03:09:17.906216 2015] [:error] [pid 3946] [client 108.162.238.215:64299] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 4
[Mon Jan 12 03:09:23.456198 2015] [:error] [pid 3931] [client 108.162.238.215:36456] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 4, referer: https://epicmc.us/404.php
[Mon Jan 12 03:09:26.631794 2015] [:error] [pid 3931] [client 108.162.238.215:36456] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 4, referer: https://epicmc.us/404.php
[Mon Jan 12 03:09:55.207111 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3925] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jan 12 03:09:55.300465 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3996] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 12 03:09:55.300511 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3996] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jan 12 03:09:59.717164 2015] [:error] [pid 4001] [client 108.162.238.215:16174] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 4, referer: https://epicmc.us/404.php
[Mon Jan 12 03:10:25.281382 2015] [:error] [pid 4002] [client 108.162.238.215:18754] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 4
[Mon Jan 12 03:11:03.812550 2015] [:error] [pid 3999] [client 108.162.238.215:47026] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 4
[Mon Jan 12 03:11:39.560256 2015] [:error] [pid 4016] [client 108.162.238.215:28585] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 4
[Mon Jan 12 03:14:36.371451 2015] [:error] [pid 4001] [client 108.162.238.215:29588] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: player in /var/www/html/stats.php on line 7
[Mon Jan 12 03:14:36.387589 2015] [:error] [pid 4017] [client 63.142.248.45:58023] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/api.php on line 9
[Mon Jan 12 03:14:36.387889 2015] [:error] [pid 4001] [client 108.162.238.215:29588] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://epicmc.us/api.php?task=stats&amp;player=): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error\r\n in /var/www/html/stats.php on line 7
[Mon Jan 12 03:14:36.387942 2015] [:error] [pid 4001] [client 108.162.238.215:29588] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: player in /var/www/html/stats.php on line 10
[Mon Jan 12 03:14:36.387956 2015] [:error] [pid 4001] [client 108.162.238.215:29588] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: player in /var/www/html/stats.php on line 20
[Mon Jan 12 03:14:36.388029 2015] [:error] [pid 4001] [client 108.162.238.215:29588] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 4
[Mon Jan 12 03:14:40.516471 2015] [:error] [pid 4001] [client 108.162.238.215:29588] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/api.php on line 9
[Mon Jan 12 03:16:26.882760 2015] [:error] [pid 4003] [client 108.162.214.137:51884] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 4, referer: https://epicmc.us
[Mon Jan 12 03:18:35.605165 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3996] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jan 12 03:18:36.649524 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4105] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 12 03:18:36.649586 2015] [core:notice] [pid 4105] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jan 12 03:18:40.845243 2015] [:error] [pid 4111] [client 108.162.238.215:26322] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: player in /var/www/html/stats.php on line 7
[Mon Jan 12 03:18:40.849347 2015] [:error] [pid 4112] [client 63.142.248.45:34942] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/api.php on line 9
[Mon Jan 12 03:18:40.849619 2015] [:error] [pid 4111] [client 108.162.238.215:26322] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://epicmc.us/api.php?task=stats&amp;player=): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error\r\n in /var/www/html/stats.php on line 7
[Mon Jan 12 03:18:40.849660 2015] [:error] [pid 4111] [client 108.162.238.215:26322] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: player in /var/www/html/stats.php on line 10
[Mon Jan 12 03:18:40.849671 2015] [:error] [pid 4111] [client 108.162.238.215:26322] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: player in /var/www/html/stats.php on line 20
[Mon Jan 12 03:18:40.850012 2015] [:error] [pid 4111] [client 108.162.238.215:26322] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 4
[Mon Jan 12 03:22:59.264503 2015] [:error] [pid 4110] [client 108.162.238.215:39205] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 3
[Mon Jan 12 03:25:15.361204 2015] [:error] [pid 4109] [client 108.162.238.215:31116] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 3
[Mon Jan 12 03:26:55.673865 2015] [:error] [pid 4108] [client 108.162.238.215:44137] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 3
[Mon Jan 12 03:26:59.193970 2015] [:error] [pid 4112] [client 108.162.238.215:43815] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: player in /var/www/html/stats.php on line 7
[Mon Jan 12 03:26:59.197756 2015] [:error] [pid 4125] [client 63.142.248.45:44475] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/api.php on line 9
[Mon Jan 12 03:26:59.197950 2015] [:error] [pid 4112] [client 108.162.238.215:43815] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://epicmc.us/api.php?task=stats&amp;player=): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error\r\n in /var/www/html/stats.php on line 7
[Mon Jan 12 03:26:59.197982 2015] [:error] [pid 4112] [client 108.162.238.215:43815] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: player in /var/www/html/stats.php on line 10
[Mon Jan 12 03:26:59.197992 2015] [:error] [pid 4112] [client 108.162.238.215:43815] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: player in /var/www/html/stats.php on line 20
[Mon Jan 12 03:26:59.198047 2015] [:error] [pid 4112] [client 108.162.238.215:43815] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/session.php on line 3
[Mon Jan 12 03:27:03.942299 2015] [:error] [pid 4111] [client 108.162.238.215:51061] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/api.php on line 9
[Mon Jan 12 03:27:16.010513 2015] [:error] [pid 4110] [client 108.162.238.215:42175] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/api.php on line 9
```

If somebody out there could re-write the entire PHP code I posted above in PHP 5 format so that I know where to start that would be awesome. Currently Apache2 is just a blank site with only a couple HTML elements working here and there. Sorry if this sounds like a noob question I'd just really like a reference.

There is two php.ini files. One is in /etc/php5/apache2

PHP INI ATTACHED EXTERNALLY BECAUSE I DON'T HAVE ENOUGH ROOM TO POST IT HERE

http://pastebin.com/UpwuC2Hj

Comment: Well you're using mysql functions which are depricated, look into [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Since your mysqli_connect() is not working too it seems that your configuration is wrong.
Can you share your PHP.ini file?

Comment: I just added it as an external link as the body of a question can't exceed 30,000 characters.

Comment: Did you install/upgrade the appropriate extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you appear to be missing the `mysql` modules for php.  installing them should get your site back up again,  then you can start on upgrading your code.

read the comments in the section **Dynamic Extensions** of the ini file and uncomment the correct line.